# What is this tiny slat for?

Tags: airliner, cabin-pressure, slats

The one labeled as "1" in the picture. And I'm having doubts about "2", it is an air supplier for cabin, right? Or am I wrong?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The item 1 is a [Krüger flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krueger_flap), a leading edge device which allows the wing to operate to a higher angle of attack. The wing-root fairing makes a small triangular segment necessary; outboard of it slats are used.

The item 2 is a [NACA inlet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18763/why-do-many-ram-air-inlets-have-this-shape) for cabin air, as commented by @mins.

Comment: In the wiki regarding Krüger flaps only Boeing is mentioned. Does it mean the Airbus is using slabs only?

Answer (score 3):

1) Appears to be where the inboard leading edge slats retract into.
2) Ram air inlet for the air conditioning/equipment cooling.