# What is the typical drag percentage of air intakes on a commercial airliner

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, inlet

I see several questions on the NACA ducts found on airliners [Example 1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16566/what-exactly-are-those-openings-in-the-bellies-of-many-jetliners/16577#16577), [Example 2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24748/whats-this-hole-on-the-atr-72/24749#24749), [Example 3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18763/why-do-many-ram-air-inlets-have-this-shape/18784#18784) and I was wondering how much drag is normally generated by these inlets?
As they take in air, I imagine there must also be some momentum losses.

I found this source, which gives a nice overview of the distribution of inlet drag for varying locations, but it's hard to judge the total amount from it.

[image: inlet drag sensitivity to location]

[Image source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268561876_Parametric_Design_Comparison_and_Evaluation_of_Air_Intake_Types_for_Bleedless_Aircraft)

**Is the inlet drag a significant portion of the total drag? What percentage of the total drag is it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legendary [Fluid Dynamic Drag](https://www.scribd.com/doc/117103507/Hoerner-Fluid-Dynamic-Drag) by Sighard Hoerner contains all the numbers you need. Chapter 9-E should be what you're looking for.